# How to sum two matrices by seq_along in r?

Tags: r, matrix, sum, apply, sapply

I have two matrices that i want to sum

```
mat1<-matrix(1:4,2,2)    
mat2<-matrix(5:8,2,2)
mat1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

mat2
 [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

what i want is this

```
mat_sum
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6   10
[2,]    8   12
```

I tried

```
mat_sum <- sapply(seq_along(mat1), function(i)
mat1[[i]]+mat2[[i]])
```

but then it doesnt return a matrix

```
[1]  6  8 10 12
```

How can i get it to return a matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do a regular `+` which will preserve the `matrix` format and does the elementwise summation

```
mat1 + mat2
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    6   10
#[2,]    8   12
```

If there are many matrices, place it in a `list` and use `Reduce` with `+`

```
Reduce(`+`, mget(paste0("mat", 1:2)))
```

Comment: Wow. That was simple. Thanks.